# Running a script in docker container and not killing the script when leaving terminal

Tags: docker, screen

I have got some docker container for instance my_container 
I Want to run a long living script in my container, but not killing it while leaving the shell

I would like to do something like that

```
docker exec -ti my_container /bin/bash
```

And then

```
screen -S myScreen
```

Then

Executing my script in screen and exit the terminal

Unfortunately, I cannot execute screen in docker terminal

Comment: What error message do you get when you run screen?

Answer (score 2):

this maybe help you.

```
docker exec -i -t c2ab7ae71ab8 sh -c "exec >/dev/tty 2>/dev/tty </dev/tty && /usr/bin/screen -r nmsrv -s /bin/bash"
```

and this is the [reference link](https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/728)

Answer (score 0):

If you have to run the script directly in an already running container, you can do that with `exec`:

```
docker exec my_container /path/to/some_script.sh
```

or if you wanna run it through Php:

```
docker exec my_container php /path/to/some_script.php
```

That said, you typically don't want to run scripts in already running containers, but to just use the same image as some already running container. You can do that with a standard `docker run`:

```
docker run -a stdout --rm some_repo/some_image:some_tag php /path/to/some_script.php
```

Comment: If the script is a php script ?

Comment: Then just run it as a php script. I've modified my answer with an example.

Comment: Is this possible to run in a container , a script that is in this container ?

Comment: Yes it works but i dont have thé script output.ans clue

Answer (score 0):

Only way I can think of is to run your container with your script at the start;
docker run -d --name my_container nginx /etc/init.d/myscript